# How do I turn a string into a "selector"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, string, switch-statement

Is it possible to turn a string into a selector?

I know that it is possible to turn it into a DOM selector:

EX:

```
var a = '.string';
var b = $( a );
```

In this way it will select the element with the `.string` class but what if in a jQuery plugin I need a string to change dinamically and then select an option or change a CSS rule?

In my plugin I have two elements, the first is positioned to the left and the second to the right. I need to dinamically change margins according to their width. Since I don't feel link doubling the code I thought if it was possible to dinamically create selectors (according to their position). With this plugin I can do what I wanted to do, but the selectors are returned as strings.

EX:

```
$.fn.myFunction( options ) {
    var cfg = $.extend({
        left: {
            selector : '.selector',
            width    : 300
        },
        right: {
            selector : undefined,
            width    : 500
        }
    }, options ),
        $wrapper = $( this ),
        left     = cfg.left,
        right    = cfg.right;

    function isDefined( e ) {
        if ( e == undefined ) {
            //do nothing
        } else {
          var align,
              $element = $( e ),
              position: {
                  right: $element.css( 'right' )
              };

        switch( position.right ) {
            case 'auto':
                align = 'left';
                break;
            case '0':
                align = 'right';
                break;
        }

        var def = 'cfg.' + align + '.width';
        var mar = 'margin-' + align;

        $element.css({
            mar: -def,
            width: def
        });
    }

    isDefined( left );
    isDefined( right );

    return this;
};
```

As you can read, I need the **def** variable to be **cfg.left.width** or **cfg.right.width** in order to *select* the relative option. Although It will always return a string. How can I  make that string work?

Plus I need to dinamically set the margins: **mar** = `'margin-' + align` wich will return for example `"margin-left"` and then use it in a css method?

Comment: Uh, if `def` is a selector, why are you setting the width and margin-top to it? `marginTop: -'cfg.left.width'` seems pretty invalid!

Comment: Infact I need that **def** which actually is 'cfg.left.width' turns into just cfg.left.width so that it can collect the width option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using bracket notation, and not strings

```
var def = cfg[align].width
```

will get you what you want

Comment: is it possible to do the same thing with a css rule? ex: $element.css( margin-[align], def ); ?

Comment: Sure, but that's just strings `$element.css( "margin-" + align, def );`

Comment: If worked for the **def** variable but not for the margin rule http://jsfiddle.net/Z5d9h/

Comment: That's because you're passing an object to `css()` and while it works with strings, it does not work with object keys.